# Process hangs and modification date does not match expected time

Tags: c#, windows, file, io

Our program seems to hang for hours, although it finishes eventually.
We see this because a file modification date is sometimes hours later than expected.

Our program PROCESS.EXE takes an IN.TXT and writes a LOG.TXT when it finishes (names changed to protect the guilty). This PROCESS.EXE is run from windows scheduler on the hour from a BAT file, and the behavior hasn't happened when we just try running from console.

To write LOG.TXT, PROCESS.EXE uses this method:

```
public static string WriteLogToFile(string message, string filename)
{
    try
    {
        string dirPath = LogFolderPhysicalPath;
        if (!Directory.Exists(dirPath)) Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath).Create();

        var filePath = string.Format("{0}{1}.log.txt", dirPath, filename);
        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            File.Create(filePath).Dispose();
        }
        using (var w = File.AppendText(filePath))
        {
            w.WriteLine(message);
            w.Close();
        }

        return filePath;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Critical exception in logger: " + ex.Message);
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

After running, the last and only line in LOG.TXT is:

> File processed in 0 hour(s) 2 minute(s) and 57 seconds.

The IN.TXT modification time was 06:55, so we would expect PROCESS.EXE to finish around 06:58 according to the elapsed time above.

However, the mod date of LOG.TXT is 09:58, three hours later. And it also appears that PROCESS.EXE actually hangs that long from other signs.

This behavior is erratic. Our process runs every hour and invariably reports an elapsed time of 2-5 minutes. Often the LOG.TXT modification date is that same few minutes after the IN.TXT modification date. But several times, like the above example, it has been 1-3 hours later.

One more thing, the logger method is called like this from PROCESS.EXE:

```
var timeTaken = (DateTime.Now - startTime);
AppHelper.WriteLogToFile(
string.Format("File processed in {0} hour(s) {1} minute(s) and {2} seconds.",
timeTaken.Hours, timeTaken.Minutes, timeTaken.Seconds),
Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
```

Because the elapsed time is computed immediately before calling this method, I don't think anything intervening could be causing PROCESS.exe to hang. What could be causing this long delay?

The LOG.TXT filename is actually created from the name of the IN.TXT file, which is some long name that has a timestamp embedded in it to make it unique. So we're not actually writing to "LOG.TXT", more like "201710050655.log".

This is running on Windows Server 2012R2.

Comment: Is it possible this behaviour is because you are only modifying the log file and not the input file. So, since your program runs every hour, the log file will be updated every hour while your input file will still have the same timestamp. Possibly, your code is processing the same input file every hour. Or do you have a way to mark the input file as processed?

Comment: Immediately after the final write above, we move the input file to another folder. So the next hour, the input folder is searched for a new "IN.txt"